# html5 video player second playlist

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video

need for my side a videoplayer with two paylisten get but not to run.
if you select a video from list one at beginning, nothing works, after selecting a video from list two the list one works.

html:

```
<label for="one">List1</label>
<select id="one">
  <option value="">- First List -</option>
  <option value="1.mp4">1</option>
  <option value="2.mp4">2</option>
  .......
</select>

<label for="two">List2</label>
<select id="two">
  <option value="">- Second List -</option>
  <option value="16.mp4">6</option>
  <option value="17.mp4">7</option>
.....
</select>

<br/><br/>

<video id="player" controls="true">
  <source id="mp4_src" src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('select').on('change', function() {
  var one = $('#one').val();
    var two = $('#two').val();
    if (!one || !two) return;
    change($(this).val());
  });

});


function change(sourceUrl) {
  var video = document.getElementById("player");
  var source = document.getElementById("mp4_src");

  video.pause();

  if (sourceUrl) {
    source.src = sourceUrl;
    video.load();
    video.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are selecting a option from list one and expecting that video source should be updated as per that selection. But that's not happening unless you select something from list2. If I understand your question correctly then here is a solution -

```
if (!one || !two) return;
```

Change To =>

```
if (!one && !two) return;
```

Here onChange listener will return **only if** user selects default options in both list1 and list2. So now even if you select something from just List1 then it should reflect in video player.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, now it works as it should
Merry Christmas

Comment: I am glad that answer helped resolve your issue :). If so, Please consider accepting it. Merry Christmas.